# Console redirect with Console.CursorLeft

Tags: c#, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine whether Console.Out has been redirected to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743885/how-can-i-determine-whether-console-out-has-been-redirected-to-a-file)
>   [How to detect if Console.In (stdin) has been redirected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3453220/how-to-detect-if-console-in-stdin-has-been-redirected)

Our system is currently using a `CursorLeft` function to write over the last thing that was printed onto the console window:

```
Console.CursorLeft = 0;
```

This is functionality that is required, so I cannot change it to just print a new line every time.

When redirecting the console to a text file, `IOException` occurs. How can I get the log file to either skip displaying these outputs or force it to write everyone of them out?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite obvious to me that the console is different from a file.
For example you can use colors in console which will be lost when you redirect the output to a file.
Thus it's not guaranteed that after redirection all console functionality can be preserved.
I would suggest questioning that requirement because it doesn't seem feasible.

Anyways here is a similar problem based on the same Win32API underneath: ["The handle is invalid" when running .net console via java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327408/the-handle-is-invalid-when-running-net-console-via-java)

Here is the article from MSDN which has some information about how the console works (in the bottom of the page): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx

Another thing to think about is that although you may not be able to fix this problem you can definitely re-architect your application, so that you abstract the direct interaction with the console with some buffer class that accumulates all the changes you want to make to a single line (or several lines) in a virtual buffer and then only make a single call to Console.WriteLine when you know for sure that all the changes were done and that line isn't going to be changed anymore.